# Javascript IoC / DI frameworks

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, ioc-container

For strongly typed static languages like Java, IoC / DI frameworks / toolkits are invaluable to decouple the complex systems thus make the sub-components unit testable and their composition fluently.

Most of us cite that Javascript as loosely typed dynamic language already offers the major benefits of IoC / DI in spirit, while some insist that higher level abstraction / implementation should be in place.

For the latter, what are those common IoC / DI implementations in Javascript realm?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look into [wire.js](https://github.com/cujojs/wire). This is my choice and it works great.

The main features are:

> - Simple, declarative dependency injection
> - A flexible, non-invasive connection infrastructure
> - Application lifecycle management
> - Powerful core tools and plugin architecture for integrating popular frameworks and existing code.
> - Support for both browser and server environments

Also please check some alternatives [npm modules for DI](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/dependency%20injection)

Comment: Only a good option if you use an application which is AMD compatible.

Comment: From the examples I also get the impression that you have to write your application IN the IoC, which is kinda defying the purpose of an IoC. I.e. your components are, or should be, independent of the IoC. E.g. in Java you do this by defining POJO's and then use an IoC to wire them together.

Comment: Why no simple example on main page? people looking for DI frameworks usually already know the advantages, so the most valuable thing should be a simple example on how to inject a dependency and get a grasp of measure of boilerplate code to quickly compare frameworks.. The HelloWire example is just too hidden into the documentation:
https://github.com/cujojs/wire/blob/master/docs/concepts.md

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's Duck-Typing allows us to easily mock dependencies.

Here is a quick example of how you could do this:

We have a simple function which represents an item being added to the database. 
DB is a dependency which we will want to mock.

```
function SaveItem(item){

    var db = new DB();

    db.insert(item);

};
```

If we change the DB dependency to be a parameter, then we can inject whatever we want.
When the function is called it checks to see if the dataStore parameter exists. When the item exists the value is assigned to db. When dataStore is null or undefined, then a new DB object is created instead. This allows you to inject in your dependency with the confidence that db will always have a value.

```
function SaveItem(item, dataStore){

    var db = dataStore || new DB();

    db.insert(item);

};
```

Now we can mock our dependency like so:

```
function mockDb(){

    return{
        insert: function(){ 
            assert(true);  
        }
    }

};
```

And to bring it all together in a test:

```
function SaveItemShouldCallInsertOnDb = function(){

    var testDb = new mockDb();
    var someTestItem = { name: "test item" };

    SaveItem(someTestItem, testDb);
};
```

Comment: Any comment on the down vote ? This seems like a rather peculiar answer to down vote on ...

Comment: The whole advantage of DI *frameworks*, is that implementations should be decided at the app or test level, and not inside functions. If I have app A, which calls service B, ... which uses service X. Then if I am the author of X and update it to need service Z, the author of App A should *not* be responsible for threading Z down App A -> B ->C ... ->X. This is the job of a DI framework like Guice or Spring. There are equivalent frameworks for javascript that can do this, but your example doesn't demonstrate how it's achievable.

Answer (score -1):

Angular.js provides a dependency management implementation which is great IMO. But Angular is much more than just a DI container, so to benefit from it your app will have to be Angular from the ground up. It's worth a try, though, especially if you have heavy form-based interactions.